# undefined reference to `sqrt', 'log',

Tags: c

When I compile this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char str[] = "3.6";

    double res = atof(str);

    printf("%f\n", sqrt(res));

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
    ====================[ Build | untitled12 | Debug ]==============================
/snap/clion/81/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/abdo/CLionProjects/untitled12/cmake-build-debug --target untitled12 -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking C executable untitled12
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled12.dir/main.c.o: in function `main':
/home/abdo/CLionProjects/untitled12/main.c:11: undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled12.dir/build.make:84: untitled12] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/untitled12.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/untitled12.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: untitled12] Error 2
```

I get same error when I replace 'sqrt' with 'log' or 'ln' ...

## compiler: cc (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math library must be linked in when compiling. Add the `-lm` flag to your gcc command, after the source or object file(s).

Comment: *to the end of the command

Comment: how to do this with `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: @M.Volf Should be something like `target_link_libraries(project_name m)`